# Java Function in XSLT Transformation

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I have this tag on XML that I need use LUHN Algoritm input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <tag>urn:epc:id:sgtin:0614141.100013.000000000001</tag>
```

I have the java code read:

```
public class Luhn {
public static String calculateCheckDigit(String card) {
.....
```

}

The code is runing perfect but now I need call the function calculateCheckDigits inside XSLT to make the transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:java="java:sumCheck.Luhn">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xmlLuhn>
        <xsl:variable name="digits" select="."/>
        Variable Digits:urn:epc:id:sgtin:0614141.100013.000000000001
        <xsl:variable name="Luhn13Digits" select="translate(concat('0',substring($digits,19,13)),'.','')"/>
        Variable Luhn13Digits = 00614141100013
        <xmlLuhn2>
            <xsl:value-of select="java:calculateCheckDigit($Luhn13Digits)"/>
        </xmlLuhn2>
    </xmlLuhn>
</xsl:template>
```

It´s not working, do you have idea how to make it ?
I already import the .jar of Luhn on the xslt project in Eclipse but nothing happens.

Comment: There are various Java XSLT implementations and whether/how you can call into Java depends on the XSLT processor you use. `version="2.0"` is usually done with Saxon 9 and there it also depends on the edition and exact version how you can interact with Java. So first find out or tell us which XSLT processor you use with Java, if it is Xalan see http://xalan.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions.html, if it is Saxon see the documentation of the particular version you use, the current release 9.8 has its documentation at http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensibility/.

Comment: Hi Martin thanks for replay. I'm using SAXON HE9 it's not on the code above because it's just example. I use SAXONH9 to make slipt of input XML to Many - href="pallet_{position()}.xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"> but now I need somehow call external .class from custom .jar to use the Luhn function.

Comment: For Saxon HE read http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensibility/integratedfunctions/, it explains how you need to set up and register your Java code in a certain way to be able to call it from XSLT. There is also an example in the resources zip for Saxon 9 I think you can download from saxonica or Sourceforge.

Comment: You have asked the same question on the Wrox P2P forum. Please don't post the same question on multiple forums - it's generally considered bad etiquette as it means wasted effort by the people who do the answering.

Comment: FWIW, [here's an XSL only implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63463728/314291) of the Luhn check digit in Xsl2.0